# iOS Swift webview reload acutal site of dynamically built Website

Tags: ios, swift, webview

I want to implement a refresh button to my iOS webview-app.

I tried it with:

```
@IBAction func refreshAction(sender: AnyObject) {
        webView.reload()
    }
```

The problem is by clicking on this button, it always loads the main-page of the webview and not the **actual** site where the user is.

Is there a possibility to reload the side where the user actual is?

**Edit:** The content of the site is build dynamically.

Comment: Well if you do it in your desktop-browser and reload at any stage, will it take you also back to the main page? If the content is built dynamically it can't reload a given site as its not a unique URL but rather the URL of the main-site itself.

Comment: i just create a demo and load my site on it. and then i tap on contact us page then reload that remain contact us page not redirect to home page. i dont know whats your code and why that happen at your side

Comment: @TMob yes the content is built dynamically. So there is no possibility to get the "real" Url of the actual site and reload this?

Comment: I'm no web-expert. But I assume thats why your standard `webView.reload()` doesn't work the way you want it to. Why do you want it to reload in the first place?

Comment: There is a desktop application with a connection to the Webcomponent. Users on the Desktop App can make changes. So the iOS App user should just refresh the site and see the changes. Then Push Notifications should be send to the iOS User with a link that opens the right site. I think I have to implement this on the Webcomponents side.

Answer (score 0):

I assume when you're first loading some website to your webview, you do something like this:

```
let url = NSURL (string: "http://someWebsite")
let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
```

So when you call `webView.reload()` it loads that initial url that was send to it

Here`s the way I recommend to solve your issue.

Implement the `webviewDidFinishLoad(webView:UIWebView)` method of UIWebViewDelegate in order to get the current website which is loaded in webView:

```
class YourViewController:UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate{

    var currentUrl:String!

    func webViewDidFinishLoad(webView: UIWebView){

        if webView.loading{

            return
        }

        self.currentUrl = webView.request?.URL?.absoluteString
    }

}
```

Now instead calling the `webView.reload()` in your button action you should call `webView.loadRequest(requestObj)` with actual URL:

```
@IBAction func refreshAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    let url = NSURL (string: self.currentUrl)
    let requestObj = NSURLRequest(URL: url!);
    webView.loadRequest(requestObj)
}
```

Comment: this gives the following exception fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: what are you returning in the if clause?

Comment: In the if clause I`m simply returning from function if the webView is not fully loaded.